# What is the [[key]]?

Tags: javascript, key, javascript-objects

I have this object:

[image]

What are the `[[Handler]]`, `[[Target]]` and `[[IsRevoked]]` keys? I search for them but cannot see anything. I try to query them with either `object.["[[Target]]"]` or `object.["Target"]`
but it doesn't work. But `object.Target` works. What is interesting is that `object.Target.Target.Target...` also works.

I'm using Firefox. The real data is under `object.Target`. But I cannot query it with `object.Target.values` (it will be the same with `object.Target.Target`. Length is 0), but `object.values`

```
app.plugins.plugins.dataview.api.page("Nghệ thuật.md")["Câu hỏi"]
Proxy {values: Array(11), settings: {…}, length: 11, defaultComparator: ƒ}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: DataArrayImpl
defaultComparator: ƒ compareValue(val1, val2, linkNormalizer)
length: 11
settings: {renderNullAs: "\-", taskLinkLocation: "end", taskLinkText: "", taskCompletionTracking: false, taskCompletionText: "completion", …}
values: (11) [Link, Link, Link, Link, Link, Link, Link, Link, Link, Link, Link]
__proto__: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

Comment: so this is how the object is represented in the browser console - which browser? Looks like Chrome/Edge - I think they are properties that are not actually accessible to code but are shown in the console for informational purposes (though your question suggests otherwise)

Comment: Just checked = not sure why you think `object.Target.Target.Target` works, since `object.Target` is **`undefined`** - unless the `proxy` happens to be proxying an object with a `Target` property, of course

Comment: @Bravo Firefox. Actually the real data is under `object.Target`. But I cannot query it with `object.Target.values` (it will be the same with `object.Target.Target`. Length is 0), but `object.values`. `object.Target` doesn't return `undefined`, but seems to return the same object with empty real data

Comment: Please show some code that demonstrates what you observe ... a picture of a console.log output is meaningless in this context ... the fact that the proxied object has a `Target` property is probably confusing you - the `[[Target]]` is nothing to do with the object you've proxied - except that all of its properties can be seen if you expand `[[Target]]` ... one of which no doubt will be called `Target`

Comment: What code do I need? The real code of the script?

Comment: code that demonstrates your issue

Comment: Not sure what code do you mean. I have added output, is that what you want?

Comment: your code that you have an issue with - I've told you what `[[Target]]` etc are, they are internal properties of the `Proxy` object you've logged to the console - they are not accessible to javascript code in the page ... they are irrelevant for the code to run ... they are included in the console.log for debugging purposes ... what is the issue you are having that has led you to log the object to the console, clearly you have some sort of issue to do that ... you are focussing on parts of the object that are inconsequential to your code

Comment: OK, here's a succinct answer to the question `What are the [[Handler]], [[Target]] and [[IsRevoked]] keys?` ... they are internal properties of a `Proxy` object, displayed on the console for the purposes of debugging, and are inaccessible to your javascript code

Comment: This is a good document that explain what's `Target` and `Handler`

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-proxy/